# not working in ie , opera how to fix?

Tags: internet-explorer, button, opera

http://jsfiddle.net/altafali/G2pLW/16/

how can i fix it to get working in ie or opera browsers?

also i want to add some delay on visibilty of this div? like timer of 30 seconds asking onclick your link will apear in 30 seconds

see in action here
http://www.symbianhome.com/ibibo-ibrowser-free-download-v2

thanks

Comment: Works fine in Opera here. Can you describe the problem you see in more detail?

Comment: working in opera after removing cache but how can i add timer after clicking on download button, like if i click on button after that attached div appear in 30 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works in Opera. For delayed show, use this. It also disables the button after clicking it.

```
<script>
var remaining=30;
function countDown() {
  remaining--; //decrease remaining
  document.getElementById('counter').innerText = remaining; //update display
  if (remaining > 0) { //more remains?
    window.setTimeout(countDown, 1000); //yes. wait again
  } else { //no. show the content
    document.getElementById('divId').style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}
function delayShow(ele) {
  ele.disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerText = remaining; //show it
  window.setTimeout(countDown, 1000); //wait for 1 second then call countDown
}
</script>

<div id="divId" style="visibility:hidden">Content!</div>

<button onclick="delayShow(this)">DOWNLOAD</button> <span id="counter"></span>
```

Comment: Where should i place span tag?

Comment: ok added script , working fine but how to add this counter with in download button, now it runs when download button pressed after that download button disappears and counter starts in small font which is not more visible, actually i need to add this type of button showing on 4shared.com as free download button thanks for help